# Using a delayed print function with input

Tags: python, input

I'm using this function to delay text:

```
def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.05)
```

Here is my current start to my program:

```
name = input(delay_print('What is your name?\n'))
delay_print('Hi, %s.' % name,)
```

This results in this when used with my name

```
What is your name?
noneAndrew
Hi, Andrew.
```

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Do you need to use `sys.stdout.write()`? Can't you simply call `print($PROMPT$)` followed by `time.sleep(0.05)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling the function inside the `input()` parameter section, you therefore let the input function prompt the user with the return value of `delay_print` (which is `None`, since it does not return anything). The way to fix this is to take it outside of the parameter section.

```
delay_print('What is your name?\n')
name = input()
delay_print('Hi, %s.' % name,)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do not invoke the delay_print function inside the input function, like this:

```
delay_print('What is your name?\n')
name = input()
delay_print('Hi, %s.' % name,)
```

Which gives you:

```
What is your name?
Andrew
Hi, Andrew.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try separating the input from the message:

```
import sys
import time

def delay_print(s):
  for c in s:
    sys.stdout.write(c)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.05)

delay_print('What is your name?')
name = input('\n')
delay_print('Hi, %s.' % name,)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running with Python 3.8+, you can use the new [assignment expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) that's supported in that version on and write the code like this:

```
import sys, time

def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.05)
    return s


delay_print('Hi, %s.' % (name := input('What is your name?\n')))
```